# null reference servicestack viewpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I have started building a controllerless MVC app built on top of Service Stack making use of 'RazorFormat'. I have built a couple of pages successfully. These pages simply map to a service that return a simple single Document object. This is all fine. I have built another view that should be returned when I access a specific route. This service returns an IEnumerable. I am able to step through the code to see that my service is returning correctly but the view never renders, I see a NullReferenceException. During debugging I am able to see that the operation name that throws is `ResourceTemplateRequest` and the stack trace:

> Error CodeNullReferenceException MessageObject reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Stack Trace at ASP.___Layout.Execute() at
>   ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage`1.WriteTo(StreamWriter writer) at
>   ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ExecuteRazorPageWithLayout(IHttpRequest
>   httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object model, IRazorView page, Func`1
>   layout) at
>   ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ExecuteRazorPageWithLayout(IHttpRequest
>   httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object model, IRazorView page, Func`1
>   layout) at
>   ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ResolveAndExecuteRazorPage(IHttpRequest
>   httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object model, RazorPage razorPage) at
>   ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest
>   httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object dto) at
>   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.HtmlFormat.<>c__DisplayClass1.<SerializeToStream>b__0(IViewEngine
>   x) at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
>   predicate) at
>   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.HtmlFormat.SerializeToStream(IRequestContext
>   requestContext, Object response, IHttpResponse httpRes) at
>   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToResponse(IHttpResponse
>   response, Object result, ResponseSerializerDelegate defaultAction,
>   IRequestContext serializerCtx, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix)

but I cannot figure out how to fix it. My service is decorated with the `[DefaultView("ResourceTemplate")]` attribute. Any ideas?

Even when I comment everything out in my view I get the exception. Here is some code

Service

```
[Authenticate]
public class ResourceTemplateService : Service
{
    [DefaultView("ResourceTemplate")]
    public ResourceTemplateResponse Get(ResourceTemplateRequest request)
    {
        var filter = factory.SetUp()
             .WithTopN(Paging.GetTopN(request))
             .WithGlobalPath(request.NodeAliasPath.StripChannel())
             .Value;

        var documents = repository.GetDocumentsByPath(filter).ToList();
        var currentDocument = repository.GetDocumentByNodeAliasPath(request.NodeAliasPath);
        var page = Paging.GetPage(documents, request);

        if (documents.None())
            throw HttpError.NotFound(string.Format("No children found for path {0}", request.NodeAliasPath));

        return new ResourceTemplateResponse
        {
            Count = documents.Count(),
            CurrentDocument = currentDocument,
            Documents = page,
            CurrentNodeAliasPath = request.NodeAliasPath
        };
    }
}


Request


[Route("/resource/{NodeAliasPath*}")]
public class ResourceTemplateRequest : DocumentCollectionRequest, IReturn<ResourceTemplateResponse>
{
    public ResourceTemplateRequest()
    {
        View = "ResourceTemplate";
        //Set base call properties
    }
}


View

@using Zoo.Optus.YesCentral.Mobile.Model
@using Zoo.Optus.YesCentral.Web.Factories
@inherits ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage<ResourceTemplateResponse>

@{
 Layout = "_Layout";

 ActivityFactory.LogPageVisit(Model.CurrentDocument.DocumentName, Model.CurrentDocument.NodeId, true);
 }


@foreach (var document in @Model.Documents)
{
@document.DocumentName.ToMvcHtmlString()
}
```

Comment: A guess... your view references a null property value that isn't known until it's rendered. MVC does the same thing. Can you provide a simple example that repro's the issue?

Comment: Looks like the error is in the _Layout file. Is it expecting something in the ViewBag?